# ipatool failed with an exception generating the ipa file

Tags: ios, xcode

I get the following error trying to generate my archives in Xcode.

[image]

I couldn't find any solution or any clue to solve the problem.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Duplicate of all of these: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ipatool+failed+with+an+exception

Comment: Thank you @matt, but already search in all that questions and I couldn't find a solution. The errors are not the same.

Comment: @Bruno did you found some workaround?

Comment: @VaibhavParmar I don't remember the issue but I think I could solve it disable some checkboxes when building the ipa file.

Comment: @Bruno haha, I solved this by disabling Rebuild from Bitcode, but that's not the solution.

Comment: Disable "Rebuild from Bitcode" option while archiving for In House

Comment: Seems to be a issue with the Mapbox framework